# If..Else or Case in WHERE Clause - something different

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements, case, where-clause

I've read loads of q&a's on here but none fit the bill for what I'm trying to achieve.
I don't even know if this is possible!  Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to build a conditional `WHERE` clause based on

```
CustID (int) = @CustomerID
```

If `@CustomerID = 0` then I want the result to be `WHERE CustID > 0` (i.e. return all customers) otherwise I only want certain customers `CustID = @CustomerID`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just do
WHERE (@CustomerID = 0 OR CustID = @CustomerID)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response antlersoft, but I need to return all customers where @CustomerID=0

Comment: @Rich - The clause given will return all customers when the parameter is zero. If the first part of the clause `@CustomerID = 0` evaluates to true the second part is ignored and all rows are matched (note the condition tests the *variable* not the table field). If the variable is not zero the first part is false and the `CustID` field must match the variable.

Comment: Ahhh, I understand what you're saying.  I just tried this and it works (sorry, shouldn't sound surprised lol).

Have you any thoughts on my other comment to Mr.?

Comment: Actually, having thought for myself for a moment I've got this sorted.  Yay for reducing 4 SP's to 1 :-)

Answer (score 7):

something like this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE 
( CASE 
     WHEN @CustomerID = 0 THEN CustID 
     ELSE 1 
  END
) > 0
AND 
( CASE 
     WHEN @CustomerID <> 0 THEN @CustomerID 
     ELSE CUSTID 
  END
) = CUSTID
```

Comment: @Rich If you just want to return all or return just 1, the @antlersoft answer is the best one, dindt see the "(i.e. return all customers)", in your question, I had to make all of this because the clause "CustID > 0"

Comment: Mr. - you are an absolute legend.  This has been doing my head in for hours before I decided to reach out for help :)

Comment: This maybe should be a separate post, but it is related and hopefully you're still around.  I've modified my SP with your suggestion and it works a treat.  I have another SP that does essentially the same thing but also allows filtering based on @FilterExpression, thus (sorry, not sure how to post it as code):

JobNumber LIKE '%'+@FilterExpression+'%' OR OrderNumber LIKE '%'+@FilterExpression+'%' OR [Description] LIKE '%'+@FilterExpression+'%' OR Client LIKE '%'+@FilterExpression+'%'

How would you suggest I incorporate this into the whole @Customer clause (i.e. filterting as customer or not)?

Comment: Thanks for the flattery, you could do something like that, the trick here, is to always make your condition true,  something like this. WHERE (JobNumber LIKE '%'+@FilterExpression+'%' OR @FilterExpression IS NULL) AND .... so on..., did you mean that?

Comment: Not quite Mr.  But I have achieved what I needed to based on Tony and Antlersoft's responses.  I really appreciate your help though!
It's a shame I can't mark both answers correct because they both work :-(

Answer (score 1):

The most common way of simulating an IF-ELSE statement in sql are CASE and DECODE (in oracle at least): 
Ex pseudocode:

`if (x == 1) then y;    else if (x == 2) then z; end if`

CASE:
`select 
    case x 
    when 1 then y
    when 2 then z
    end example
from dual;`

DECODE:
    `select decode(x,1,y,2,z) example from dual;`

Comment: Thanks for that - The other answers provided a workable solution.
I appreciate you taking the time to respond!